# How do I sort a integer column ascending and descending?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend

```
const [customerList, setCustomerList] = useState([]); //store all that information of the database in a list
  //make an axios request to get information from database
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/customers").then((response) => {
      setCustomerList(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const [counterCount, setCounterCount] = useState(0);
  function sortCountCustomer() {
    const sortedCountCustomer = [...customerList];
    let sortCountVisit = counterCount;
    //check the current sortCount, if it is 2 then go back to 1, if not then increase by 1
    if (sortCountVisit === 2) {
      sortCountVisit = 1;
      setCounterCount(1);
    } else {
      sortCountVisit += 1;
      setCounterCount(sortCountVisit);
    }
    console.log(sortCountVisit);
    if (sortCountVisit < 3) {
      sortedCountCustomer.sort(function (x, y) {
        if (sortCountVisit === 1) {
          return x.counts_of_visit > y.counts_of_visit
            ? 0
            : x.counts_of_visit
            ? -1
            : 1;
        } else if (sortCountVisit === 2) {
          return x.counts_of_visit < y.counts_of_visit
            ? 0
            : x.counts_of_visit
            ? 1
            : -1;
        }
      });

      setCustomerList(sortedCountCustomer);
    }
  }

  function getCountArrow() {
    if (counterCount === 1) return "↑";
    return "↓";
  }

<th class="countheader" onClick={() => sortCountCustomer()}>
                        Counts of Visit {getCountArrow()}
```

I have the following function on an integer column but it does not work when I click on the header count visit . So My code doesnt work whne I click the header column on count of visit, which has different integer values, would like to sort it to asecedning and descending.

Comment: does the sort code even run? do you get any output in the browser developer tools console? I see the `sortCountCustomer` function, but not how you call it

Comment: @JaromandaX Hi Jaro I edited my code question below to show the 
<th class="countheader" onClick={() => sortCountCustomer}>
                        Counts of Visit {getCountArrow()}

Comment: `() => sortCountCustomer` doesn't call the function ... it returns the function, is that what you meant? or did you mean `() => sortCountCustomer()`

Comment: @JaromandaX ok I edited that in but my sorting for the integer values don't work
So my column has a a few numbers integer. 5 7 9 2 13, I want to sort it in ascending and descending order

Comment: rather than the ternary operator, just `return x.counts_of_visit - y.counts_of_visit` and `return y.counts_of_visit - x.counts_of_visit` as appropriate - because your ternary doesn't make sense

Comment: Well doesn't the normal JS `sort()` works for you?

Comment: @jateen - sort without a callback does not work with object properties!

Comment: @jateen wait so do I use .sort() or what now

Comment: @JaromandaX obviously pass the callback as well.

Comment: @jateen so what do I change in my sorting code?

Comment: @jateen ... what `sort` does `sortedCountCustomer.sort` use then? why would it NOT be the "normal" JS sort?

Comment: @max - I've told you what to use

Comment: Well I couldn't understand much of your code, maybe if you have an array [ 5, 7, 9, 2, 13 ], I believe you can simply use 
arr.sort( (a, b) => a - b)) ?? would do the trick sorting it into ascending order.

Comment: @jateen can post an answer

Answer (score 1):

Although couldn't understand much of your code. But as per my limited understanding of what problem you are facing, you can try the implementing the below logic.

```js
let arr = [
  { val: 5 },
  { val: 7 },
  { val: 9 },
  { val: 2 },
  { val: 13 }
];
//For sorting in ascending order
console.log(arr.sort((a, b) => a.val - b.val));
//For sorting in descending order
console.log(arr.sort((a, b) => b.val - a.val));
```

Comment: ```
 return x.counts_of_visit - y.counts_of_visit
            ? 0
            : x.counts_of_visit
            ? -1
            : 1;
        } else if (sortCountVisit === 2) {
          return y.counts_of_visit - x.counts_of_visit
            ? 0
            : x.counts_of_visit
            ? 1
            : -1;
```

I need change my logic for this one

Comment: Sorry max, can understand the implementation you have done. I will try later to check your code with a fresh mind.